# BCNF Decomposition & 3NF

Tags: database, database-relations, bcnf

I'm working through problems in my textbook to get ready for my test, and I'm having a pretty tough time with figuring out this question.

Consider a relation 
S(B,O,I,S,Q,D)

FDs: S->D, I->B, IS->Q, B->O

I need to do the BCNF decomposition, and then determine all of the keys of S.
I did BCNF decomposition and determined that IS is a superkey, but I can't figure out the rest of the decomposition to figure out the other keys.

I also need to find a minimal bases for the given FDS, and use 3NF synthesis algo to find a loseless-join dependency-preserving decomposition of S into 3NF.

Any help is much appreciated, I am beyond confused here and am really struggling with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

{I S} is the only key, and this is easy to show. The attributes I and S appear only in the left parts of functional dependencies, so they *must* belong to any key. And since they are already a (super)key, no other key exists.

The functional dependencies are already a minimal cover (or minimal base) since: a) every right part has only one attribute; b) in the dependency IS→Q no attribute on the left part is superfluous, and c) no dependency is redundant.

So the 3NF decomposition is:

R<sub>1</sub> < (B O),
{ B → O } >

R<sub>2</sub> < (B I),
{ I → B } >

R<sub>3</sub> < (I S Q),
{ I S → Q } >

R<sub>4</sub> < (D S),
{ S → D } >

which is equal to the result of the decomposition in BCNF.